# Checkpointing implementation

Tags: c++, linux

I already checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73583979/12469912) but the answers didn't help. I am new to C++ and please bear with answering my question. Concerning checkpointing, how should it be coded to take the capture of a running program in C++?

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing) and [2](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/%7Ejplank/plank/papers/USENIX-95W.pdf) suggest:

> The most basic way to implement checkpointing, is to stop the application, copy all the **required** data from memory to reliable storage (e.g., parallel file system) and then continue with the execution.

The memory doesn't always contain the running program data and other data corresponding to the OS and some other applications (if running) may be present in the memory. So how to obtain only the **required** data from memory and how the whole process can be coded? I am not looking for an exact code but would like to have some hints to know how to code it.

Comment: Checkpointing is about being able to pick up where you left off if something goes awry. So your application needs to keep track of where it is, so that if it has to be restarted it won't have to repeat everything it's done up to that point.

Comment: I think this highly depends on the application, for some it will be impossible - e.g. opened sockets cannot be just closed and restored later, opened files can be gone...anything dealing with OS will likely not be 100% restartable.

Comment: @PeteBecker My question is how to capture and store the state of the program at that specific point?

Comment: It is your (the program author) job to know where the required program data is. There is no general one-size-fits-all method of finding it.

Comment: @Bsh -- that depends on what the program is doing. There's no general answer for that. Silly example: if the program has to repeat some task ten times, from time to time it can write to a file how many times it's done it. If it gets halted, when it gets restarted it can look in the file to see how many times the task has already been done.

Comment: If you want your program to do it, you need to write code that will periodically save your program's in-memory data structures to disk (using any standard I/O API) and also code that can read a saved file and use it to re-create the original data structures again.  There's no automatic way to do that, unless you count running your program inside a virtual machine and using VMWare (or whatever) to save/restore the state of the entire virtual machine -- which would work, but that's a lot of additional overhead that you might want to avoid.